# A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly -- Using HttpClient

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I am receiving connection attempt failed to my web api service when I called the service from asp.net mvc application. If I call the service from a browser or from MVC application hosted on another server, it works.

It also works if I host the application in test server or development server.

It doesn't work only when I host the application on that server and  call the service from the mvc app.

Any suggestion. Is something on the hosted server is blocking the connection.

```
   using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string baseUrlFromConfig = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["webServiceUrl"];

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrlFromConfig);

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            Uri myUri = new Uri(baseUrlFromConfig + "api/account/ConfirmEmail?e=" + e + "&code=" + code, UriKind.Absolute);

            var response = client.GetAsync(myUri).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: How's your server code?

Comment: Check your firewall settings !

Comment: Hello there, What was your work around regarding to this issue? Have you found any solution to that and if you do, do you mind to share it?